# ¿Agregar archivo php como si hiciera require_once mediante enqueue_script o funcion similar en Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme, wordpress-widget

Quiero crear mi propio **Widget** el cual quiero que aparezca debajo del resto de widgets originales del theme original en el menu de admin.

Quiero hacerlo de la manera más limpia y menos chapucera posible así que mi intención es no tocar los archivos del theme original.

En vez de modificar el archivo del tema padre, he creado uno en el tema hijo cambiandole el nombre porque el original esta agregado usando *`require_once`*.

Si el archivo original se llama *`Widgets-area.php`* al mio le he llamado *`widgets-area-2.php`*.

Los he tenido que llamar diferente porque sino habría un conflicto ya que al ser un *`require_once`* solo se puede agregar una vez un mismo archivo php y he puesto solo el código necesario sin repetir el código original.

El problema de hacer esto es que en el menu de widgets en el menu del admin, aparece el widget que he creado yo al principio del resto en lugar de aparecer debajo de los demás widgets como era mi intención, ya que en el fichero donde está el código HTML donde se incrustan estos widgets si lo he agregado debajo del resto que es donde me interesa. El *`require_once`* está hecho en el *`functions.php`*.

Así que pensé si habría una manera limpia de encolar con un *`enqueue_script`* un `archivo.php` como haciendo un *`require_once`* pero agregandolo después de que el archivo de widgets original sea agregado, agregando después el mío.

He probado lo siguiente en el archivo *`functions.php`*:

```
function add_own_widget() {
    /*--------------------------------------*/
    /* Admin Panel
    /*--------------------------------------*/
    wp_enqueue_script( get_stylesheet_directory() .'/functions/return-smof-data.php' );

   /*--------------------------------------*/
   /* Include functions
   /*--------------------------------------*/
   require_once( get_stylesheet_directory().'/functions/widgets/widget-areas- 2.php' );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_own_widget');
```

Esto por lo que he podido comprobar no funciona.

¿Hay alguna manera de conseguir que aparezca mi widget debajo de los demás?

No sé que más detalles proporcionar. Lo he hecho añadiendo el código mínimo necesario para que funcione, de la primera manera que he mencionado pero aparece al principio. De la segunda manera no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

plugins, y demás elementos en Wordpress no aparecen dependiendo el orden de carga de los ficheros!!!
En el propio functions al agregar los widgets tienen una prioridad u orden de carga, solo debes ordenarles utilziando estos numeros.

Ejemplo del add_action

```
add_action( string $tag, callable $function_to_add, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1 )
```

Ese priority es con el que jugar.

Te dejo  un enlace interesante: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_widget

Comment: Lo siento, no funciona. Me parece que no se pueden agregar archivos .php usando wp_enqueue_script.
Como dije con el require_once agrega el area de widget pero en el menu aparece al principio aunque en el html aparece al final, donde quiero que aparezca, pero en el menu no queda del todo bien que aparezca antes que el resto.